# Issue with redirect on $location in Angularjs - Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have got plenty working, but at present I am stuck.

I have included a module for running parse.com authentication / login etc which I have added below.

I am trying to get the app to redirect on a successful login to /tab/friends by setting $location.path however I simply can't get it to work. In console I get  Cannot read property 'path' of undefined.

I've been fighting this for two days, so any help would be super welcome :)

My parse related module:

```
    // JavaScript Document
    angular.module('AuthApp', [])
    .run(['$rootScope', function( $scope, $location) {
      $scope.scenario = 'Sign up';
      $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();
      $scope.location = $location;

          console.log(location);
          // $location.path('/tab/friends');

      function randomString(len, charSet) {
        charSet = charSet || 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        var randomString = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var randomPoz = Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length);
            randomString += charSet.substring(randomPoz,randomPoz+1);
        }
        return randomString;
    }

    var randomValue = randomString(9);

      $scope.signUp = function(form, $location) {
        var user = new Parse.User();
        user.set("email", form.email);
        user.set("firstname", form.firstname);
        user.set("lastname", form.lastname);
        user.set("mobilenumber", form.mobilenumber);
        user.set("username", form.email);
        user.set("password", randomValue);

        user.signUp(null, {
          success: function(user) {
            $scope.currentUser = user;
            $scope.$apply();
          },
          error: function(user, error) {
            alert("Unable to sign up:  " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          }
        });    
      };



      $scope.logIn = function(form, $routeParams, $location) {
        Parse.User.logIn(form.username, form.password, {
          success: function(user) {
              console.log(location);
                  $location.path('/tab/friends');
            $scope.currentUser = user;




          },
          error: function(user, error) {
            alert("Unable to log in: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          }
        });
      };

      $scope.logOut = function(form) {
        Parse.User.logOut();
        $scope.currentUser = null;

      };
    }]);
```

My app.'s code that starts everything up

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js

// here we add our modules first then after that we start up our main app/module of 'starter' in the brackets to the right of that we have to include the modules that we want to load in too



angular.module('AuthApp', []);
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'AuthApp'])




.run(function($ionicPlatform,$rootScope,$location) {

    $rootScope.location =$location;



    $ionicPlatform.ready(function($routeParams,$location) {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)



    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }



  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })

    // Each tab has its own nav history stack:



    .state('tab.friends', {
      url: '/friends',
      views: {
        'tab-friends': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-friends.html',
          controller: 'FriendsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.friend-detail', {
      url: '/friend/:friendId',
      views: {
        'tab-friends': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/friend-detail.html',
          controller: 'FriendDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

        .state('tab.me', {
      url: '/me',
      views: {
        'tab-me': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-me.html',
          controller: 'meCtrl'
        }
      }
    })


    .state('tab.settings', {
      url: '/settings',
      views: {
        'tab-settings': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-settings.html',
          controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

.state('signup', {
        url: '/signup',
        templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
         controller: 'SignupCtrl'
    })

     .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
         controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })





    .state('firstview', {
        url: '/firstview',
        templateUrl: 'templates/firstview.html',
         controller: 'FirstviewCtrl'
    })



  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/firstview');


});
```

Comment: Try: `.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location)`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I tried this but it just ended up breaking the views / app.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have the following :

```
// JavaScript Document
angular.module('AuthApp', [])
.run(['$rootScope', function( $scope, $location) {
```

You are using dependency injection in the `.run`.  Unfortunately, you are not injecting `$location` properly.

Change it to this :

```
// JavaScript Document
angular.module('AuthApp', [])
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function( $scope, $location) {
```

Comment: Thank you - I really appreciate you taking the time to reply. I tried changing that as you noted - however, the app still won't redirect when the 'login' function runs. The login does work as the current user gets set and I can read it into console, but the redirect doesn't happen.

Comment: Just an update - I removed the $location, $scope etc from the functions such as login, and was then able to make it work. Switching the netbeans has let me see how it highlights where it is 'calling' further up the code so that helped me click the answer. Thank you again for your help as it really was the bit I have been missing :D